# Error when creating the linked service for Hubspot in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, connector, hubspot

I am trying to pull data from Hubspot to ADF using the Hubspot connector in ADF.
I have also registered Hubpost with the Azure AD.
Followed the steps as per the doc, still unable to create the linked service.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-hubspot#linked-service-properties

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzoIU.jpg)

I have used Postman app to generate the Access & refresh tokens.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Hubspot developer account, Select the scope. Then use the Postman app, to generate the Access and refresh tokens by entering the required parameters. Use the POST method to get the tokens.

[image]

[image]

Use the fresh tokens generated in the ADF linked service to establish connections.

Once the connection is established, Hubspot will list the tables which are available and can be copied using ADF.

[image]

Create a new pipeline in ADF, select the Lookup activity, then the copy activity to copy the desired table into the destination.